# Error parsing INI config file: unrecognised option 'nohttpinterface'

Tags: mongodb, config, ini

Do you guys know how to fix this error during mongo startup?

```
Error parsing INI config file: unrecognised option 'nohttpinterface'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which version of MongoDB you are running, but since 3.6 the REST API and interface has been removed, along with the config option you are describing.

You can read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#http-interface-and-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Remove the rest = true line(option) from mongodb.conf file